# Need advice on how to create node class for r/b tree in java

Tags: java, treenode, red-black-tree

We have been asked to implement a Red Black Tree in java, but not i'm exatcly sure how this is done. It would be really nice if anyone would comment on my node class for the r/b tree implementation. Here we go:

```
public class RBTnode {

public RBTnode(int key, RBTnode left, RBTnode right) {
    /* this is the constructor for a root node */
    color = 0;
    parent = null;
    key = this.key;
    left = this.left;
    right = this.right;
}

public RBTnode(int key, RBTnode left, RBTnode right, RBTnode parent, int color ) {
    key = this.key;
    color = this.color;
    left = this.left;
    right = this.right;
    parent = this.parent;

}

int color; // 0 black, 1 red
int key;
RBTnode parent;
RBTnode left;
RBTnode right;
```

}

Comment: So what's about your code? Is it working? Is there a problem (which)? ... what is your question?

Comment: I'm wondering whether it is a good idea to create two constructors like I did, because we will only need the first constructor once obviously, as we only have 1 root? Also is it the right move to assign the parent node as well as the children as a RBTnode? I dont know if it works yet, but my idea is that i want to create a arraylist, which should contain RBTnode objects, in another class togehter with the methods (insert, traverse tree etc.).

Comment: maybe turn around `parent = this.parent;` etc ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't written  a RB tree myself, but I am learning about them right now. From what I've been told, It seems that you need some adjustments.

There are certain rules that you need to follow in order for a RB Tree to be a RB Tree:

- Every node is RED or BLACK
- Root node is always BLACK
- New nodes are always RED
- Both children of a RED node is BLACK.
- Every path from a root to a leaf, or to a null child, must contain the same number of black nodes.

That being said, I don't think you need the second constructor because no matter what, you are always going to initialize a new node to RED.

Comment: Im learning about them as well, so i know all those requirements for a binary search tree to be a r/b tree, but yes, i think it's too much with 2 constructors.

Comment: Make the first constructor call the second and it's all a moot point. That's just the basics of good code, unrelated to whatever you're doing.